# Выпадающее меню, где внутри картинка. На чистом CSS

Tags: html, css

Ребят, привет. Как сделать выпадающее меню.
Чтобы при нажатии на название открывалось меню, а внутри была картинка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделать обычное выпадающие меню и внутри добавить картинку. Где ваш код? Что именно не получается?

Comment: Я еще не начинал. Просто не знаю с чего начать делать именно это. Т.е. просто сделать выпадающее меню и вставить туда картинку? Так просто? :D

Comment: @Ярослав Ну так сначала пробуйте, а потом уже спрашивайте, если что не получается (уже с примером попытки). Никто же за попытку руки не отрезает...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar не получается даже попробовать. Я структуру для этого меню не понимаю :( Какая должна быть структура в HTML, чтобы при нажатии на список выходила картинка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант на `:target`.
Считайте код уже готов к использованию, осталось стили подправить.

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.menu img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.menu .item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu .item:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}

.menu .drop > .item::before {
  content: '+';
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  color: green;
}

.menu .drop > .droped {
  display: none;
}

.menu .drop:target > .item::before {
  content: '-';
  color: red;
}

.menu .drop:target > .droped {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div id="drop1" class="drop">
    <a href="#drop1" class="item">Картинка внутри</a>
    <div class="droped">
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Image"><br>
        <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="item">Невыпадающий блок</a>
  <div id="drop2" class="drop">
    <a href="#drop2" class="item">Выпадающий с ссылками внутри</a>
    <div class="droped">
      <a href="#" class="item">Ссылка 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">Ссылка 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">Ссылка 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="item">Ссылка 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Подробнее о [:target](http://htmlbook.ru/css/target)